# Redirect after sending password reset link in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, authentication, redirect, laravel-5.1

How can set a redirect path after sending the password reset link?

In the *ResetsPaswords trait* is this code:

```
switch ($response) {
    case Password::RESET_LINK_SENT:
       return redirect()->back()->with('status', trans($response));

    case Password::INVALID_USER:
       return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
}
```

But I don't want to change the vendor files. Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the trait code a successful result redirects back to the same route:

```
redirect()->back()->with('status', trans($response));
```

Please notice the `status` variable in the `with()` method. This sets a temporary session variable which you can then use inside your view template to e.g. notify the user that the email has been set successfully.

```
@if (session('status'))

// ... notification that the email has been sent

@else

// ... your original form for submitting an email address

@endif
```

The point is, it is usually not necessary to redirect to another route just to tell the user the email has been sent. You can use the same route with the same view and create two blocks of code within the view. One which generates the form for submitting the email address, another one which generates the success notification.

Comment: Not sure why this is the accepted answer. This doesn't provide a solution.

Answer (score 11):

You can do this by adding `protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';` to your `PasswordController`.

So your controller would look like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class PasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

    //The rest of the controller below this...
```

And you can customise the route by changing `/dashboard` to where you wish to redirect them.

You should check out the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#after-resetting-passwords) for more info.

Comment: This redirect is after the password reset, the question is how to redirect after sending the activation link (after inserting your email)...

Answer (score 1):

You'll notice in the `ResetsPasswords` trait the following two functions: `getSendResetLinkEmailSuccessResponse` and `getSendResetLinkEmailFailureResponse`, which handle the redirection after sending the password reset email, depending on whether the reset email was sent successfully or not.

A good reason to change this is if (as in my case) you want to return the user to the main login screen after the password reset link is sent.

To do this, simply change your `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController` and override the function, like so:

```
protected function getSendResetLinkEmailSuccessResponse($response)
{
    return redirect()->route('login')->with('status', trans($response));
}
```

Comment: I assume you're using the PasswordController that Laravel creates with the `make:auth` command? And that it uses the `ResetsPassword` trait? What version of Laravel are you on?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.1 (see the title) but I don't remember using `make::auth` command

Comment: Do you have a `PasswordController.php` in `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController`? Can you paste the entirety of that file?

Comment: I have the default `PasswordController.php` that comes with Laravel 5.1 and I added your code beneath `function __construct()`

Comment: I got `Route [login] not defined` with this code, even though `php artisan route:list` shows my login route OK. `return redirect('login')->with('status', trans($response));` works, though you need to copy the `session('status')` section from your passwords/mail template into your login template to see the msg.  Laravel 5.2, used `make:auth`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to edit the vendor files. Just open /app/Http/Controllers/Auth/PasswordController.php and add following line of code in PasswordController class

```
    protected $redirectPath = '/DesiredUrl';
```

Tested on Laravel 5.1

Comment: This changes the redirect after the reset link is clicked and the user changes his password. The question asks how to change the redirection after the reset link is SENT.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me, add the following to your `ForgotPasswordController`:

```
protected function sendResetLinkResponse(Request $request, $response)
{
    return redirect()->route('login')->with('status', trans($response));
}
```